# Understanding $P(X_1<\beta-\epsilon)=\frac{\beta-\epsilon}{\beta}<1$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, ..., X_N$ be independent observations over the random variable X ~ $U(0, \beta)$ (uniform random variable from 0 to $\beta$).

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

I'm trying to understand the following statement:

$P(X_1<\beta-\epsilon)=\frac{\beta-\epsilon}{\beta}<1$.

How is this statement true and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of $X_1$ is $f(x)=(1/\beta) \mathbb{1}_{[0,\beta]}(x)$ because $X_1$ is uniform on $[0,\beta]$.

Therefore $P(X_1 < \beta - \varepsilon)=\int_0^{\beta - \varepsilon} 1/\beta \  \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\beta - \varepsilon}{\beta}<1$

I don't really know what to say about its meaning, I can only "translate" it into English, it means that the probability for $X_1$ to be less than $\beta - \varepsilon$ is $\frac{\beta - \varepsilon}{\beta}$, which is of course less than $1$.